# Custom Swagger Documentation Setup for Internal and Client Use with Tailored Endpoints and Operations

Tags: django-rest-framework, swagger-ui, drf-spectacular

I need to set up Swagger documentation for both internal and client use, with custom HTML templates for each. For internal documentation, I need to display all endpoints along with all their operations. However, for client documentation, I only want to show a select few endpoints along with the relevant operations specific to those endpoints. Is it possible to achieve this using preprocessing hooks in 'drf-spectacular'?"

I have created custom swagger template for both client and internal purpose and try to hide end points via java script, but does not work